JSONPATH Typescript not picking up any values
I've got a JSON path with a condition to pull out if config item is valid based on the key name. When using https://jsonpath.com/, the path works, and it correctly picks out the correct value:

Typescript code:
import * as jsonpathPlus from 'jsonpath-plus';

const key = "configTwoEnabled"           
const configCurrentValue = jsonpathPlus.JSONPath({ path: `$.featureSwitches[?(@.key == "${key}")]`, json: jsonResponse })[0];

The JSON response is populated. If I put $. I get all the values. When I add featureSwitches path, it doesn't return anything. Here is the sample JSON:
{
    "featureSwitches": [
        {
            "key": "configOneEnabled",
            "isEnabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "configTwoEnabled",
            "isEnabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "configThreeEnabled",
            "isEnabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "configFourEnabled",
            "isEnabled": false
        },
        {
            "key": "configFiveEnabled",
            "isEnabled": true
        }
    ]
}


Hard to tell without more context on what jsonResponse is, but gathering by the name of it I'm guessing jsonResponse is not the object you think it is, perhaps a Promise? The code works if you substitute  jsonResponse with the raw JSON object.

Your code seems to work for me if you substitute jsonResponse for the object you specified.
If $. returns the whole list as you said however, then I suspect that jsonResponse variable holds the following JSON object instead:
[
    {
        "key": "configOneEnabled",
        "isEnabled": true
    },
    {
        "key": "configTwoEnabled",
        "isEnabled": true
    },
    {
        "key": "configThreeEnabled",
        "isEnabled": true
    },
    {
        "key": "configFourEnabled",
        "isEnabled": false
    },
    {
        "key": "configFiveEnabled",
        "isEnabled": true
    }
]

You could probably modify your path to $.[?(@.key == "${key}")] (without the featureSwitches). But it is hard to know without you showing what is the jsonResponse object.
